# Bitbucket: why allow 1 but not 0 commits behind the target branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, pull-request

In Bitbucket (cloud), one can configure a merge restriction to require a PR branch to be at most a certain number of commits behind the target branch. An interesting use case I see is to require the PR branch to be "in sync" with the target branch, which is the same as being 0 commits behind.

However, one cannot specify "0".

[image]

This has already been asked as a feature request here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22431. I was just wondering what could possibly be the (technical?) reason for not allowing "0" here? Is not even that you can do it by upgrading to a more expensive plan.

Comment: i wouldn't know of a _technical_ reason.... but if it's a big project with a lot of people and many things going on at the same time, it would be a pain if everybody had to forcefully rebase all their current work just because a PR was merged.

Comment: Good point, thanks.  Still, to me, it would be up to you to choose 1 or 2 instead of 0, or not to use this check at all. Why allow >=1 and not 0?

Comment: Perhaps checking the option needs a valid constraint in place, for 0 value meaning no maximum commits behind destination branch this option shall not be ticked originally.